# while passing multiple parameter to nvarchar in stored procedure result is not getting

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IBS_fetchrequested]
@tid integer =null,
@tbarcode as nvarchar(500)
--@Tbaroced dbo.TBarcode readonly

as 
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON;
if (select COUNT(*) from  Khanger_tbl where tid=@tid and requested=1 and delivered=0)>0
begin
select t.TBarcode,k.HBarcode as keyloc from Khanger_tbl k
inner join transaction_tbl t on k.transactid=t.transactID
 where tid=@tid and requested=1 and delivered=0 and t.Tbarcode not in(@tbarcode) and t.status=3
end

end
```

*this tbarcode value i am passing like this :'450','451','452'*
then i executed this stored procedure manually

```
USE [Vallett]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[IBS_fetchrequested]
        @tid = 20,
        @tbarcode = N'''450'',''451'',''452'''

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

but in result still getting that tbarcode...what is wrong with my stored procedure?
Result

```
TBarcode             keyloc
-------------------- --------------
450                  50
451                  51
452                  52
```

i want the result not include this TBarcode

Comment: A *single* string that *happens* to contain commas and quote characters is not at all the same thing as *multiple* strings being passed to `IN()`

Comment: so,,what i have to do here?

Comment: Ideally, use a data type that is actually *designed* for storing multiple values, such as a table-valued parameter or XML. Less ideally, do a search on SO or the web in general for any of ~5 billion questions where people find out how to split a string on commas in SQL Server.

Comment: sir i already passing my srting seprated by comma...

Comment: No, you're currently passing a string that *contains* commas. I was telling you that if you wanted to do that, then you need to find a way to *split* the string apart into multiple values. There are *plenty* of examples of that to be found be a simple search.

Comment: ok,,,i will check,,there s no other method to do this?